# Should I be applying to international jobs requiring a work visa right now when I know getting my IELTS results will take 1-2 months?

Tags: job-search, visa, international

Here's my situation. I am interested in jobs which require a work visa, and the visa requires a decent IELTS score. Due to the scarcity of test dates, I know I won't get the results before the end of March, which means I won't be able to accept an offer for a month or two.

Is it wise to apply anyway? I know applying and tailoring CVs/resumes is time-consuming, but I wouldn't want to receive a positive response before then and have to turn it down. I assume they're not going to wait a month when they could just get somebody else... I also wouldn't want to explain my situation and get a negative response because of that, knowing that perhaps this response would have been positive had I waited at least a little bit till I get my results...

I want to wait, but my parents are pressuring me. I don't know whether they are right to do so, or if they are simply trying to sabotage my chances abroad because they secretly want me to stay in my home country, which I hate. (This wouldn't be the first time, which is why I am very doubtful and prefer to ask...)

Another possibility would be preparing the CVs/resumes and waiting before sending them, but I am afraid the job posting will be gone in a couple months and I would have wasted my time tailoring everything for nothing.

So, what would you do if you were me? Or rather, what would most people do in this case? I'm sure I'm not alone.

Comment: "_I am afraid the job posting will be gone in a couple months_". Sure, but they'll be other job postings in 1-2 months. Maybe better ones!

Comment: @neubert Yes, sure! But I would have to re-tailor everything to the new company, which might not have the same requirements and policy. I take it your advice would be preparing the CVs/resumes and then editing them slightly to accomodate for new postings?

Comment: If they have an email address listed as a contact, just ask whether that fits their timeline. My expectation for hiring from abroad would be that they expect delays anyway, but they might still want to see the test results before they make larger investments like sponsoring visa.

Comment: "_But I would have to re-tailor everything to the new company, which might not have the same requirements and policy. I take it your advice would be preparing the CVs/resumes and then editing them slightly to accomodate for new postings?_". Yes. It shouldn't take you 8h to apply for each and every job. imho you ought to blanket sent out your resume en masse and spending 8h or whatever for each job customizing your resume for individual jobs isn't conducive to that.

Comment: Honestly? You should have done the test 2 or 3 months ago. Companies usually accept results in the last 6 months as “current”.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I know, some don't require anything at all and the interview is enough, but the work visa requires the new IELTS UKVI and I couldn't sit it since my ID was out of date (I didn't know), getting all of it in order took a long time... and due to the brexit (I suppose?) there were few spots to take the specific UKVI test, which brought me here... but yes, I agree, I should have been more pragmatic. Many institutions consider results in the last *2 years* as valid actually.

Answer (score 3):

Send them immediately. It's clear your English is fine.

If someone wants to hire you, and it even comes up, and you finally go through all the weeks of bureaucracy towards a visa ... if you don't have the score by then you'll simply be saying to (someone), oh I'm doing that test on Friday.  It's a non-issue, just go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

It is never going to be faster than if you applied now.  So go ahead and apply now.  The worst that happens is that you get experience with interviewing, which is not such a bad thing.

You should look into whether you can take the test without a pending visa application.  IELTS test are generally considered valid for 2 years.

Companies may not be willing to pick you if you can’t start with a certain timeframe, but they aren’t going to hold it against you.